Is it permissible to donate or sell organs that you can live without?
For example it's possible to live with only one kidney and it's still possible to have children with only one testicle.
Do donating or selling these organs have any prohibitions and if so which ones? Would it matter if it was pekuach nefesh or not for the recipient?

One is allowed to accept organs from living people, provided the recipient’s life is at risk without the donation, the donor’s life is not at risk, and no organs are harvested from the living to store in organ banks for future use.  However, giving blood is allowed even if just to store in a blood bank and even if the donor gets paid. [Rav Moshe Feinstein, Igrot Moshe, Choshen Mishpat 1:103]
Compensation for organ donation is not mentioned and is presumably allowed.
